# Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 4684514

Tags: hard-drive, format

I'm trying to format a hard drive.

I've used `mkfs.ntfs /dev/sda1` after the `fdisk` command, but `mkfs` doesn't work!
And when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> I see this message:

```
Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 4684514
```

Have I lost my hard drive? If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The error message **may** point to a hardware error.

**Warning!** The below command **deletes** all data currently written to your `/dev/sda1` partition!

Please run:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda1 bs=1048576
```

This command should abort after writing as many mebibytes as your partition is large. If it aborts before with an error, or if `dmesg` shows hard disc I/O errors, your [HDD](https://www.mirbsd.org/wtf.cgi?HDD) is bad, and you ought to move the data off it and trash the bad disc [ASAP](https://www.mirbsd.org/wtf.cgi?ASAP).